# Tomcat 7.0.47 - Windows - Missing Unhandled Exceptions/ Stacktrace

Tags: java, tomcat, logging, error-handling, windows-7

Tomcat 7.0.47 - Windows 7 - Default install.

Unhandled exceptions are not going to console and not appearing in any of the logfiles under apache-tomcat-7.0.47\logs.

Console and catalina.2015-04-16.log are being written to just missing errors. System.out.println going to console (but not catalina.2015-04-16.log). System.err.println also goes to the console. But runtime errors such as unhandled exceptions do not! Where can they be?

Looked at the /conf/logging.properties file:

```
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = catalina.

2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE
2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = localhost.
```

Not sure where to go from here. As a diagnostic I am purposely causing a nullpointer exception. I am putting a System.out.println before it and after it. The before System.out shows up in the console. The after does not (which is what i would expect) but the unhandled exception is nowhere to be found.

Stumped...

Answer (score 1):

Okay I found the problem. It was simple. The /conf/logging.properties file, contains the logging level at a default to FINE. I was used to earlier Tomcat versions so a level of FINE seemed to me that it would be very detailed, apparently not. After setting the logging level to "ALL" ("FINEST" may well have worked also). Unhandled exceptions started appearing in the console log.

The portion of the /conf/logging.properties file is as follows:

```
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = ALL
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = catalina.

2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE
2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = localhost.

3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE
3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = manager.

4host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE
4host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
4host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = host-manager.

java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = ALL
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
```

I changed the first and last set (1catalina.org and java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler) to ALL.